# What is the name of the document/amount of money you need to temporarily give the government in order to leave the country?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I don't know how this works in other countries, but in Iran, when you want to leave the country, say, on business, you need to post bail, which can consist of either an amount of money or a piece of property with cash value, which will be returned to you after you get back. Can we use the word "bail" or is there a more suitable word for such an occasion?

Comment: In the US, bail is for jail. You could try *collateral*.

Comment: Not too long ago they had the same kind of rules for leaving Ireland. This could also be thought of as a bail but that is short for a bail-*Bond* which is to say a promise to return or forfeit the bond. Another good word for it is a *Ransom*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you're looking for the word *bond* (certainly not *bail*):

> **bond** *n*
> a. A guarantee issued by a surety agency on behalf of a client, requiring the surety to pay a sum of money to a third party in the event the client fails to fulfill certain obligations; a surety bond.
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bond)</sub>

Absent that, *surety* itself could work for you.

> **surety** *n*
> 2. (Law) security given against loss or damage or as a guarantee that an obligation will be met

Comment: *Bond* may be an OK term for this purpose, but the quoted definition of *bond* does not seem to be applicable to the OP's case, as no surety **agency** is involved in what is described in the question.